# Yarn build error compiling angular/components(github code) width include bazel

Tags: angular, yarnpkg, bazel

The code in github: https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/DEV_ENVIRONMENT.md

When I download the code from github and ran the command `--yarn build`, I received the error below：
Who knows how to solve it?

```
F:\front-end\angular-component>yarn build

yarn run v1.22.0
$ node ./scripts/build-packages-dist.js
######################################
  Building release packages...
  Compiling with Ivy: false
######################################
info No lockfile found.
$ node ./tools/npm/check-npm.js
warning package-lock.json found. Your project contains lock files generated by tools other than Yarn. It is advised not to mix package managers in order to avoid resolution inconsistencies caused by unsynchronized lock files. To clear this warning, remove package-l
ock.json.
[1/5] Validating package.json...
[2/5] Resolving packages...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/typescript: ESOCKETTIMEDOUT".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "F:\\front-end\\angular-component\\yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
INFO: Repository npm instantiated at:
  no stack (--record_rule_instantiation_callstack not enabled)
Repository rule yarn_install defined at:
  C:/users/chenjianlong/_bazel_chenjianlong/lo7ziovu/external/build_bazel_rules_nodejs/internal/npm_install/npm_install.bzl:434:16: in <toplevel>
ERROR: An error occurred during the fetch of repository 'npm':
   yarn_install failed:  (info No lockfile found.
$ node ./tools/npm/check-npm.js
warning package-lock.json found. Your project contains lock files generated by tools other than Yarn. It is advised not to mix package managers in order to avoid resolution inconsistencies caused by unsynchronized lock files. To clear this warning, remove package-l
ock.json.
[1/5] Validating package.json...
[2/5] Resolving packages...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/typescript: ESOCKETTIMEDOUT".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "F:\\front-end\\angular-component\\yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
)
```